# iOS でSSIDを取得し、そのSSIDに対して接続するアプリを作りたい。

Tags: ios

こんにちは。

iOSのアプリで無線LANのSSIDを取得し、そのSSIDに対して接続を行いたいです。
SSIDの取得に関してはサンプルソースがたくさんありますが、その先の接続に関してはどこにも記載がありません。

英語版のこのサイトを見ると、Wifiには接続できないよー的なことが載っている気がするのですが、英語がよくわからないので、何が正しいのかわかりません。

Wifi接続はアプリからできないのでしょうか？

ご教授いただきたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ここ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/4810)で同様の質問がなされていますが、残念ながらiOSではアプリからWi-Fiアクセスポイントの選択・接続操作は行えないというのが結論です。
『既に接続しているWi-Fiスポットで認証処理を行う』ということなら可能で、Japan Wi-Fi等のアプリがそれにあたります。

Comment: ありがとうございました！！！！